# Error al realizar una migracion en laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

estoy realizando una migracion para mi tabla contactos la cual es la siguiente:

create_contacts_table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->Auth::user('idOwner')->id;
            $table->string('position');
            $table->string('mobile_no');
            $table->string('email');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

El error esta en donde uso el Auth del usuario que esta logeado, lo que yo quiero intentar hacer es que en el campo de mi tabla llamado idOwner, me guarde el usuario que esta logeado al momento que se carga el contacto, para saber bien que usuario carga cagada contacto. Alguno sabe si es un error de sintaxis? o directamente es un error de logica?

Comment: Sí, es un error de sintaxis y de lógica. [Aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types) tienes los tipos de columna disponible. Lo que puedes hacer en la migración es [crear una columna que referencie al id de la tabla users](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) y el valor se lo asignas al insertar cada registro

Comment: En ese caso podemos votar para su cierre cierto @porloscerrosΨ ?